# How to create a method that can write into a file repeatedly

Tags: java

I have a method where I create a new instance of `PrintWriter`:

```
public class Clazz {

    File temp = new File("temp.txt");

    private void saveInTempFile(String text) {
        try (
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(temp, true));
        ) {
            pw.write("text: " + text + '\n');
            pw.close();     
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to call this method at various points in my program and I want to add a new line (with the variable `text`) to the `temp` file. However, at this state, it only writes into the file the first time I call this method. I have tried it both with and without `pw.close();` with no difference.

I need a new line to be added every time I call this method, yet only the first line is added.

It doesn't strictly have to be done using `PrintWriter` nor `FileWriter`

I would very appreciate any help, please.

Comment: You could open the PrintWriter and then save it so that you don't have to close it until you're finished using it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to show the exact behaviour you describe. Also include the output you get when you executed your MCVE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I use the following (I don't find it efficient).

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

public class Clazz {
    protected PrintWriter out;
    private String outFileName;
    private String prefix = "";

    public Clazz(){
        this.outFileName = "test";
    }

    private void createOutput(String outFileName) {
        try {
            this.out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Couldn't open file '" + outFileName );
                    // "' for report output\n" + e.getMessage(), e);
        }       
    }

    protected void write(String txt) {
        if (out == null) {
            createOutput(outFileName);
        }
        out.println(prefix + txt);
    }

    public void done() {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args){

        Clazz obj = new Clazz();

        String output = "hi 1\n";
        obj.write(output);

        String output2 = "hello 2\n ";
        obj.write(output2);

        obj.done();
    }
}
```

[image]